# JFrame won't open through ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Trying to make pong, and I'm very nearly done. I have it set up so when a player scores 5 points, another JFrame opens. On that JFrame, there are two buttons; one to play again, and one to open a scoreboard (a record of the last three games). For some reason, I can't get the button to open the scoreboard. Would love some help figuring out what's wrong.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class scoreBoard extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawLine(0, 50, 200, 50);
        g.drawLine(0, 100, 200, 100);
        g.drawLine(0, 150, 200, 150);
        g.drawLine(95, 0, 95, 230);

        g.drawString("PLAYER 1", 15, 30);
        g.drawString("PLAYER 2", 115, 30);

        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[0][0]), 15, 80);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[0][1]), 115, 80);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[1][0]), 15, 130);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[1][1]), 115, 130);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[2][0]), 15, 180);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(gameOver.Score[2][1]), 115, 180);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scoreBoard board = new scoreBoard();

        JFrame boardFrame = new JFrame("Score Board");
        boardFrame.setSize(200, 230);
        boardFrame.setVisible(true);
        boardFrame.setResizable(false);
        boardFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        boardFrame.add(board);
    }
}
```

This is the class I have for the scoreboard.

```
scores = new JButton("Recent Scores");
scores.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        scoreBoard board = new scoreBoard();
    }
});
```

This is the ActionListener I have in place to open the score board.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a constructor for Scoreboard? At the moment, all I see is a main method, which will not be instantiated on a default constructor call.

Comment: Have a look at your scoreBoard's main method, there is an example of what your actionPerformed method should be doing

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I still think I made two valid points in my original comment.  But as it has caused confusion I will remove the comment and refrain from commenting in the future.

Comment: The OP is not a mind reader. The OP doesn't know what YOU think needs to changed in the "example" code found in the main() method. My comment simply listed problems with the "example" code. I made the same comment in the other answer. I don't know why it generated so much discussion.

Comment: @camickr First, sorry, yesturday was not a "good" day, so everything bite hard, this was not an attack on you. I simply commented that the "start" of the answer they were seeking was already in their code, but there was no attempt to re-use it. Yes, you are right, it's not the best example, but it was a start which could have gotten the OP one step closer. IMHO, the question doesn't belong on SO, as it's not only has it been answered before, but could be answered through better resources, not an attack on you. It just berwilders me that they already had the code, but didn't re-use it

Comment: @camickr I would have commented regardless if someone else had answered the question and at the time, the answer did not appear accepted from my end (if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all class names should start with an upper case character so your class should be `ScoreBoard`.

```
public class ScoreBoard extends JPanel {
```

Your `Scoreboard` class is a JPanel

```
ScoreBoard board = new ScoreBoard();
```

Your actionListener code just creates a panel. You can't display a panel unless you add it to a window.

You should display you scoreboard in a JDialog (not a JFrame).

The basic code would be:

```
scoreBoard board = new scoreBoard();
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.add( board );
dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible( true );
```

That is basically the code from the main() method needs to be added to the ActionListener, except you use a JDialog, not a JFrame. Also you would use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead of `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using this main function, instead, you're starting your program from a different main (the one that makes contains your button).

When you run a program (assuming you use an IDE, such as Eclipse) only one main function is executed, therefore, *this* main does not.

Move all code from main to the actionPerformed() method.

Note that this is not an optimal solution, because it will create a new JFrame each time you press the button. Better approach would be to show/hide one JFrame.

Comment: `Move all code from main to the actionPerformed() method.` - no you should not be doing that. Read my comment to the original question and then check out my answer.